# How to install a software manually?

Tags: install-from-source

I have recently learnt how to install programs from the terminal and would like to know the meaning of a few commands that I use to install. For example, I downloaded **python 3.2** from [source](http://python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/Python-3.2.2.tar.bz2) and extract and try to install it but failed. I saw in the explanation in other sites that I must use `./configure` and `make` and `make altinstall`.

When I do that, it installs the software but not the suggested packages. Why is that? And what's the meaning of `./configure` and `make` and `make altinstall`? And why do all manually installed software be installed only by this or not at all?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Why doesn't it install suggested packages? / Why do all installed packages have to be done by these commands only or not at all?***

The commands you are using is to install the downloaded package alone, when the downloaded package is actually a binary source package. That installs just the downloaded package alone. In order to install `.deb` packages you can use [dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/dpkg.1.html) and even better why not use trusted packages from Ubuntu sources to download packages? You can use the [apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/apt-get.8.html) command for that.

***What's the meaning of `./configure`,`make` and `make install`?***

You can get a full understanding of what these commands are and what they do from [this link](http://www.codecoffee.com/tipsforlinux/articles/27.html) and [this link](http://tldp.org/LDP/LG/current/smith.html), but here is a short excerpt from one of them summarizing the commands:

> - You run `configure` *(you usually have to type `./configure` as most    people don't have the current directory in their search
>     path)*. This    builds a new Makefile.
> - Type `make` . This builds the program. That is, make would be executed,    it would look for the first target in Makefile and do
>     what the    instructions said. The expected end result would be to
>     build an    executable program.
> - Now, as root, type `make install` . This again invokes make, make finds    the target install in Makefile and files the directions to
>     install    the program.