# Is there a Paint.net Equivalent on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gimp

I have tried GIMP and the tool I am looking for is not in it. I have looked into paint.mono but have no clue on how to install it. I just need an art program with a simple Curve tool, where draws a curve through specified multiple points.

Comment: [This question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/105122/how-to-install-a-software-manually) may be helpful if you want to install PaintDotNet in Linux.

Comment: Are you actually looking for a Paint.NET alternative? I think you're looking for a vector editing application reading the question body. Paint is just bitmap based if I'm correct.

Comment: @FoxyRK9 You said GIMP doesn't have the tool you need. Will [the paths tool](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-using-paths.html) not do what you want?

Comment: @Eliah, there is package called paintdotnet which was originally called paint-mono. And [here](http://linuxundich.de/en/ubuntu/paint-mono-paint-net-fur-linux/) is the instruction of how to install it on Linux.

Comment: @Danatela Cool! Will that provide a port of the latest version of Paint.NET? I'm guessing not, since recent versions of Paint.NET are no longer [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_open_source_software). Either way, it would be a big help if you were to post an answer about how to install it that way! The feature the OP is asking for is not confined to vector graphics editors like Inkscape, and even an old version of Paint.NET would probably be more suitable if the OP's needs primarily involve raster editing.

Comment: A while back when i had windows XP, I had Paint.net and did some images in there. Now I have ubuntu 12.04 and need to find a program with a tool for creating curves like Paint.net. I tried to install Via @Danatela 's way, but its not working. I tried Play On linux and WINE. I have Tried the other programs, Gimp, Krita, and Inkscape and they all drive me insane trying to do a basic feature I had Paint.net.

Comment: Well, if it is not working, edit your question and try to highlight the problem. I.e. running it in a terminal and showing the output containing error description would be most suitable. @Eliah, I will try newer version of PDN and see what's wrong with it. Running the older, however, gave me feeling that everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Inkscape [image: Install inkscape]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkscape). And here's the project website: http://inkscape.org/

You might be interested in a tutorial on curves: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBENwo72SfE

Comment: Tried Inkscape and it drove me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [Pinta](http://pinta-project.com/)

You should be able to just install it with `sudo apt-get install pinta`

[image: Pinta screenshot]