# I need CURL due https support

Tags: curl, https

I'm trying to build APT.  However, the configure script crashes saying

> configure: error: failed: I need CURL due https support

How do I enable https for CURL?

EDIT: My question is different, and I solved it anyway.  I know how to use apt-get, if I didn't I wouldn't be trying to build it in the first place.  The error message gave no clue which package that needed to be installed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a software manually?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/105122/how-to-install-a-software-manually)

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by installing `libcurl4-openssl-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```